# Is it possible to disassemble & reassemble an iOS IPA file from the command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, phonegap-build

I've got an issue with how [PhoneGap:Build](http://build.phonegap.com) is currently building iOS applications: [splash screens are duplicated, greatly increasing the compiled file size](http://fusiongrokker.com/post/phonegap-devs-how-do-you-keep-file-size-down) of my applications.

Previously they had an issue wherein [they were copying the wrong icon into the Android XHDPI icon folder](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/9) for Android builds, and I was able to write a script that [automated fixing this bug post-build](https://github.com/atuttle/pgb-fix-icon) since they seemed to show no interest in fixing the bug (almost a year now since the original bug report & while it seems it might be fixed presently, they haven't commented lately).

I know that I can rename an IPA to a ZIP, unzip it, and browse its contents. I could automate the following steps easily:

1. Rename
2. Unzip
3. Find & remove originals for splash screen images via config.xml file
4. Re-zip (& rename?)

...But I'm not sure where I'd have to go from there. I've found a few threads that discuss using Xcode to run different utilities, perform signing, etc; but they all seem to assume you've got an xcode project locally, which I don't. (I use PhoneGap & PhoneGap:Build specifically to avoid those headaches.)

I'll have access to all of the same key files that are uploaded to PhoneGap:Build for the original signing process, and I know all of the necessary passwords. I have Xcode installed (just not a local xcode project)...

Is it possible to re-assemble a "fixed" zip into a signed IPA for dev/release distribution using command line utilities & without creating a local Xcode project? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. 
You can export an IPA, unzip it, delete the duplicate file (assuming your code doesn't reference it), then re-sign the app and zip the IPA back up. 
You'll find examples on how to use the commandline tool "codesign" to resign a .app directory on stackoverflow!